# change user under which Tomcat is running

Tags: tomcat

i am using Apache tomcat 7 on windows 8.
i tried to change user under which Tomcat is running (https://superuser.com/questions/301864/run-tomcat-service-as-different-user-on-windows-7)
my computer->manage->services->Apache tomcat->Log on and i added my username and password.
but when i tried to run tomcat,i got this error:
Error 1069:The service did not start due a log on failure.what should i do ?
***how to know the right username and password?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a windows (system) user and use its username and password. The user needs acess rights to your Tomcats folders.